# Accessing and using a datatemplate textbox in xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, textblock

Normally when I create a textbox I can use it in visual studios like so.
xaml

```
<TextBlock Name="BedNumberTextBlock" FontSize="26" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0">
```

c#

```
BedNumberTextBlock.Visibility =Visibility.Collapsed;
```

However when my textblock is enclosed in a data template I cannot find it to control its visibility. Could some one show me how to find the textblock and collapse its visibility please?

Comment: in which datatemplate do you place the TextBlock? you have to use `VisualTreeHelper` looking for at least the `ContentPresenter` and use the `FindName` method of the DataTemplate. You can also use just the `VisualTreeHelper` to look for the TextBlock.

Comment: `DataTemplate` are displayed by something, this something has property to access content, simply cast it to `TextBlock`.